# Is it possible to determine a legendary item by the graphics?

Tags: diablo-iii

Without identifying an item, is it possible to determine if it is a particular legendary item over another?

In particular, is it possible to figure out which of the 5 set rings a green ring is from without identifying it?

Comment: I know an unidentified Blackthorn's Breeches has the same graphic as an identified one.

Comment: You can at least limit the possibilities by ilvl. This works very good with weapons.

Comment: Why is being able to do this important to you? I don't mean for that question to be rhetorical... I'm genuinely curious about the use-case for this. Is there a trade market for un-identified items?

Comment: Legendary items below 50 dont show their ilvl at all, like any other item.

Comment: @Sterno yes there is and my friend suggested that I keep a recent set ring I found unided since he said it wasn't a natalyas and I was wondering how he knew.

Comment: @Sterno the unided market is pretty booming for example an unided hellion crossbow can sell for 600-750k

Comment: @yx. Awesome. I had no idea!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specifically, no.  4 of the 5 rings use non-unique graphics as shown [here](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/ring/#type=set).  Only Natalya's Mark has a unique graphic.

You can narrow down the list by graphic but not uniquely determine which you have.